# How to get the combinations of a string (vowel or consonant)?

Tags: python-3.x, combinations, python-itertools

Number of possible combinations for the given Indices
for example the indice[0] of the word `BANANA`
should give me :

```
{'B',
 'BA',
 'BAN',
 'BANA',
 'BANAN',
 'BANANA'}
```

```
word='BANANA'
indices=[0,2,4]
def find_combinations(word:str,indices:list):
    a=[''.join(l) for i in range(len(word)) for l in combinations(word, i+1)]
    b=[x for x in a if x.startswith('B')]
    return b
```

output:

```
set(b)
{'B',
 'BA',
 'BAA',
 'BAAA',
 'BAAN',
 'BAANA',
 'BAN',
 'BANA',
 'BANAA',
 'BANAN',
 'BANANA',
 'BANN',
 'BANNA',
 'BN',
 'BNA',
 'BNAA',
 'BNAN',
 'BNANA',
 'BNN',
 'BNNA'}
```

desired output:

```
{'B',
 'BA',
 'BAN',
 'BANA',
 'BANAN',
 'BANANA'}
```

Comment: You don't need the **combinations** and reduce the results.  It's just some prefix_sum variation.   Question is what the indices used for - it's not clear.

Comment: yes you are right @DanielHao, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the combinations, based on index on a given word, forward way.

```
word = "BANANA"
indice = [0,2,4]

def find_comb(word:str, indice:list):
    final = []
    for i in indice:
        local = []
        new = ""
        for j in word[i:]:
            new = new + j
            local.append(new)
        final.append(local)
    return final

print(*find_comb(word, indice), sep='\n')
```

This will give you list of lists as combinations index wise.

Output:

```
['B', 'BA', 'BAN', 'BANA', 'BANAN', 'BANANA']
['N', 'NA', 'NAN', 'NANA']
['N', 'NA']
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need combinations, and you can generate prefixes starting at a specific index pretty easily using [slices](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=slice#slicings) and `range`.

```
from typing import List

def get_parts(word: str, start: int) -> List[str]:
    return [word[start:i] for i in range(start + 1, len(word) + 1)]
```

(Obviously you can change to `return { ... }` if you need it to be a `set`.

```
>>> get_parts("BANANA", 0)
['B', 'BA', 'BAN', 'BANA', 'BANAN', 'BANANA']

>>> get_parts("BANANA", 2)
['N', 'NA', 'NAN', 'NANA']

>>> get_parts("BANANA", 4)
['N', 'NA']
```